# TX nLocktime and mempool

Tags: transactions, mempool, locktime

Where is a broadcasted TX located at before it's nLocktime reached? in mempool or not? I have tried a lot can't figure out. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Such transactions are located only with the transaction creator. Nodes generally do not keep in their mempool transactions that cannot be immediately mined.

Answer (score 0):

further to Achow's answer, here an extract from Andreas' bitcoin bible ("Mastering Bitcoin, 2nd edition"):

> If nLocktime is nonzero and below 500 million, it is interpreted as a
>   block height, meaning the transaction is not valid and is not relayed
>   or included in the blockchain prior to the specified block height. If
>   it is above 500 million, it is interpreted as a Unix Epoch timestamp
>   (seconds since Jan-1-1970) and the transaction is not valid prior to
>   the specified time. Transactions with nLocktime specifying a future
>   block or time must be held by the originating system and transmitted
>   to the bitcoin network only after they become valid. If a transaction 
>   is transmitted to the network before the specified nLocktime, the
>   transaction will be rejected by the first node as invalid and will not
>   be relayed to other nodes.